# How to configure Elasticsearch to start at boot?

Tags: boot, 16.04, services, elasticsearch

How do you make Elasticsearch start at boot time on Ubuntu 16.04? I've installed elasticsearch from the standard repo with:

```
sudo apt-get install elasticsearch
```

and it works fine. However, I have to manually start it with:

```
sudo service elasticsearch start
```

after I login. I've tried the usually trick for configuring services to start at boot with:

```
sudo update-rc.d elasticsearch defaults
sudo update-rc.d elasticsearch enable
```

but that's done nothing.

```
$ systemctl status elasticsearch
* elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2017-02-05 17:11:59 EST; 8h ago
     Docs: http://www.elastic.co
 Main PID: 9133 (java)
   CGroup: /system.slice/elasticsearch.service
           `-9133 /usr/bin/java -Xms2g -Xmx2g -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -server -Xss1m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encod
```

Comment: `sudo service elasticsearch enable` may do the trick

Comment: What does `systemctl status elasticsearch` report?

Comment: @muru, I've updated my question.

Comment: You need `systemctl enable elasticsearch`